# iPhone apps won't update

Tags: iphone

I try to update apps, and it asks for a password.  I enter the password, and then it asks for a password again.  How do I get it to accept my password?

Answer (score 1):

You might then need to log out of your account on your phone by tapping on your id in Settings > iTunes & App Store and then log back in so as to 'refresh' the account on it.

If that doesn't fix it (if the account was disabled by iTunes Support then it might not) then contact iTunes Support : http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/ - click on Contact iTunes Store Support on the right-hand side of the page

Answer (score 0):

I think just turn off your phone and then turn back on and sit on the AppStore of what app your trying update and I think a update butten will come up.. Bc not all of them can update by itself it normal

Answer (score 0):

Also to get it to save your password just keep putting it in. And you can go to setting and go to iTunes and apps and then you can put it in